# Cucumber Ruby running multiple scripts using Tags option not working

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cucumber, bdd

I am trying to run multiple scripts in Cucumber Ruby using tags options and it is throwing error

Below is the cucumber script

```
@excel @chrome @sprint1
Feature: RegistertoGmail2
Scenario:RegistertoGmail2
```

Command from cmd to run

```
cucumber --tags @sprint1
```

error message

```
C:\Ruby22\Project\Play>cucumber --tags @sprint1
DEPRECATED: #default_wait_time= is deprecated, please use       #default_max_wait_time= instead
invalid option: --tags (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
C:/Ruby22/Project/Play/features/cuke-steps.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-     2.1.0/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:99:in `load'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-  2.1.0/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:99:in `load_code_file'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-2.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:232:in `load_file'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-2.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:99:in `block in load_files!'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-2.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:98:in `each'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-  2.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:98:in `load_files!'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-2.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:262:in `load_step_definitions'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-2.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:65:in `run!'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-2.1.0/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:32:in `execute!'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-2.1.0/bin/cucumber:8:in `<top    (required)>'
C:/Ruby22/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby22/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
```

The option which i have tried as suggested was

```
C:\Ruby22\Project\Play>cucumber features -t @sprint1
DEPRECATED: #default_wait_time= is deprecated, please use   #default_max_wait_time= instead
invalid option: -t (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
C:/Ruby22/Project/Play/features/cuke-steps.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-  2.1.0/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:99:in `load'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-2.1.0/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:99:in `load_code_file'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-2.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:232:in `load_file'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-2.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:99:in `block in load_files!'
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-2.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:98:in `each'
```

C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-2.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:98:in `load_files!'
    C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-2.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:262:in`load_step_definitions'
    C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-2.1.0/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:65:in `run!'
    C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-  2.1.0/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:32:in`execute!'
    C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/cucumber-2.1.0/bin/cucumber:8:in `<top    (required)>'
    C:/Ruby22/bin/cucumber:23:in`load'
    C:/Ruby22/bin/cucumber:23:in `'

Please kindly advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try with

```
cucumber features -t @sprint1
```

Or update to the latest Cucumber version and try

Comment: Thanks i was able to solve the issue ... it is more with updating project to the latest version of cucumber.

Thanks all

Comment: @Achyuth - Happy to hear that the issue is resolved. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to update to the latest Cucumber version and try again, if that fails maybe try this command:

```
cucumber -r features --tags @sprint1
```